# really funky C# compiler behavior with nullable literals

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, null, nullable, literals

The C# 4.0 compiler does not complain about this (not even a warning):

```
if(10.0 > null + 1)
{       
}

if (myDoubleValue > null)
{
}
```

And it seems to be always false. What is going on here? Is null automatically converted to `Nullable<double>` or something?

If so why doesn't this work then:

```
double myDoubleValue = null + 1;
```

Also, why would I ever want such a behavior. Why is it a good thing that it is possible playing around with literals like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason the assignment doesn't work is that the result is of type `double?`, not `double`. The result will always be the null value for the `double?` (aka `Nullable<double>`) type.

Oh, and both of the first two blocks *should* make the compiler complain, with warnings like this:

> Test.cs(7,19): warning CS0458: The
>   result of the expression is always
>   'null' of type 'int?'
>   Test.cs(12,13):
>   warning CS0464: Comparing with null of
>   type 'double?' always produces 'false'

Managing to compile without errors isn't the same as not complaining :)

Comment: Right I had accidentally turned off warnings. With warnings turned on I wouldn't even have to ask the question as the compiler explains everything in the warning.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(10.0 > null + 1)
{

}
```

is actually equivalent to:

```
int? i = null + 1; // i.HasValue = false in this case
if(10.0 > i)
{

}
```

so you are actually trying to compare a non nullable type to a nullable type which doesn't have value.

```
double myDoubleValue = null + 1;
```

doesn't compile because the type on the right hand is `int?` and not `double`.

Also is this question just out of curiosity in attempt to #%=^ the compiler or you are actually writing something like this in a real project?

Comment: Of course not. I had a typo in my code wich yielded wrong behavior. While debugging I discovered the typo and wondered why no one warned be about this. Only to notice later on that I accidentally disabled the warnings tab in visual studio.